# Cannot Get Counter_Cache to update properly in Padrino (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, padrino

I have a Padrino app I am building where I want to use counter_cache. I am using ActiveRecord as my ORM. In my Repository model, I want to keep a count of the number of contributions that are associated with a given repository. Here are the relevant models:

```
class Repository < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :contributions, autosave: true
  has_many :users, through: :contributions

  validates :full_name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

end

class Contribution < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :repository, counter_cache: true

end 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :contributions
  has_many :repositories, through: :contributions

  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true

end
```

The schema is as follows:

```
  create_table "contributions", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "repository_id"
  end

  create_table "repositories", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "full_name"
    t.integer  "contributions_count", :default => 0
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
  end
```

I have created a test in Rspec to check to see that the contributions_count is updating properly. However, I cannot get it to pass. Here's the spec:

```
  describe "when a new contribution is created" do
    it "updates the counter cache" do
      repo = Repository.create(full_name: "sample_repo")
      user = User.create(username: "sample_user")
      expect {
        Contribution.create(user: user, repository: repo)
        }.to change {repo.contributions_count }.by(1)
      end
    end
```

When I run the spec, I get the following failure:

```
  1) Repository when a new contribution is created updates the counter cache
     Failure/Error: expect {
       result should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/models/repository_spec.rb:43:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have also tried creating Contributions in the console and it is not updating the repository counter_cache. I've tried a bunch of stuff, but can't seem to figure out how to get it to work properly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because your `repo` object isn't being magically updated by Ruby when the `Contribution` object is being saved to the database. You will need to reload the information from the database:

```
repo.reload.contributions_count
```

Comment: I updated the code as suggested, but now I get the following error `Failure/Error: repo.reload.contributions_count   ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:  
Couldn't find Repository without an ID`